# Postgresql: How to take incremental backup with Barman

Tags: postgresql, backup, barman

I am new to Postgresql, I've found a tool named Barman for taking incremental backup of database. But the few tutorials aren't helping that much as they're not for naive users.

Can someone help explaining the steps simply how to backup data with Barman? That would be a great help ! I'm using Postgres 10.4 in Ubuntu 18.04.

Answer (score 2):

With Barman, the only way to do it is to use `rsync` backup method and to enable links. See example :

```
backup_method = rsync 
reuse_backup = link
```

If you need advanced configuration about incr and diff backups, maybe you should have a look at pgbackrest tool.